android - how to check, which dependencies are really used
In my gradle file I have many dependencies e.g.:
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1"

As I have a huge project and during debugging I tested many methods and libraries I included many dependencies in gradle file. After deleting tons of code, now I don't know, which dependencies are still used in my project.
Is there a way to find usages of each dependency in gradle file?
When I right click on a dependency,and select Find Usages, it says Cannot search for usages from this location.

You could comment off each implementation line and see where the build fails.

really? it would take a whole day, there almost 50 dependencies. it should be possible with running command gradlew dependencies, but it doesn't report anything

@Darksymphony use command ./gradlew :app:dependencies it will print complete tree and for unused dependency you can try this.

./gradlew :app:dependencies (for example) should show the tree of dependencies and their versions, but my understanding was that you wanted to find out which kotlin (or java) code uses 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'. There may be a better way than my suggestion, I do not claim that it is the best or quickest way.

no, I want to know, which from 50 dependencies in my gradle file are really used (needed) across my project, so I can delete those from gradle, that are not used. Appcompat was just an example.

gradlew :app:dependencies somehow works, but it is showing even kotlin dependencies and tons of other that are not implemented directly in my gradle file. I wanna check only those from my gradle file

@BobSmith thanks, but no clue how to use that plugin which you linked

@Darksymphony its already there Add to your project and use section. I think this is the best library which you can see currently over the internet . :)

i tried but it says can't find the plugin. But anyways thanks

Simply navigate to

Code --> Analyze Code --> Dependencies

Then choose the scope as an example "Whole Project" and hit analyze button.
Done! Now you can see all dependencies which are used like following screenshot.
Screenshot
If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted answer.

excellent and so simple, I completely missed this option. Thank you!
